# Firebase Admin pointing to the wrong Google Cloud Project when using Cloud Natural Language API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, google-natural-language

I have a project on GCP with a project-id and a google service account which I have been using to access the Cloud NLP API all along until recently, over the weekend, when it stopped working. Now I get an error which says:

> Cloud Natural Language API has not been used in project 563***33**** before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/language.googleapis.com/overview?project=563***33****

The thing here is that the `project-id=563***33****` is different from the one used and specified in my project IAM & Credential interfaces and I don't know where this new project-id is coming from. I have enabled the API on the console and when I access it with gcloud CLI it shows that it's been enabled. But when I try to access it from my project, on Cloud Functions, it throws the error above.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has appeared recently to some users. Try running

```
gcloud services enable language.googleapis.com
```

once again on the affected projects.

Comment: Hi @aemon4, I have tried this and still got the situation reported above. It enables it on the CLI and can be visibly seen on the console, but my project continues to point to another (the wrong) project Id

Comment: Try to disable it first `gcloud services disable language.googleapis.com` and then re-enable it, this worked for the other users

Comment: Hi @aemon4, I have done this over and over again, to no avail

Comment: If the workaround did not resolve your issue, you could contact the corresponding team of [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) in order to investigate your issue.

Comment: Hi @ArtemisGeorgakopoulou, I have done that. Thanks